# VB asp.net detect if the pdf has a hand written signature

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a document that requires two hand written signatures.

We email or fax the document to person A.
Person A signs it and fax/emails it back to us.

We need to then upload the signed pdf into our web app we developed and we need to have the system auto check if there is a signature in the area for Person A.  We could put an identifier next to where they should sign so it know to look for pixels in that area or how else can we tell it to look for a signature or more than X amount of pixels next to an identifier.

We then take the document signed by person A and send it to person B  They sign it and send it back to us and we need the same process to happen.  Look to the designated area where B signs  so we can auto mark that document as B signature.

Comment: depending how accurate you need to be, this could be quite complicated. Image recognition has whole books and vast numbers of academic studies focused on it

Comment: We dont need to be accurate in terms of what the signature is.  We just need to know if there is something scribbled there.

Comment: DocuSign. Just do it.

Comment: OK so what exactly are you stuck with? what have you tried?